# dropdown menu not working on ebay

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have the following dropdown menu: http://jsfiddle.net/McKgU/ which as you can see works fine. However When out on eBay the layout is all over the place.

Comment: You're probably running into issues with other CSS selectors overwriting your own. You'll want to make your custom selectors more specific. Try using a tool like Chrome's Dev Tools (F12) or FF's FireBug to see if your CSS is being overwritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/McKgU/5/

What I've done:

1) Prefixed your "menu" `id` with #NOINTERFERE00_

Why? Since "menu" is a fairly common name choice for ids/classes/whatever, the likeliness of there being another element on the page with the same name is very high. This ensures that there's no interference (css or js) between your 'menu' and any other element with the id "menu" on the page.

2) I've added !important to the end of each css declaration.

Why? It's also very likely that the author of the page you're inserting this into has styles targeting ul's, li's and a's. This ensures yours take precedence (unless the author is using important on his own stylesheet. He shouldn't in most cases, but might.)

What I haven't done:

3) Reset all the styles applied by the original author's stylesheet to ul, li and a's. (I'm still figuring out the better way to do it)

[Scoped CSS](http://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/) solves both problem 1 and 2 in a more elegant way. However only Chrome supports is at the moment, I believe.

Comment: taking a look  at it now. I'll come back soon

Comment: Copy and pase the html and css exactly as is from here - http://jsbin.com/alagiq/1/edit - into your ebay page. The html and css you currently have has some invalid characters which are messing up the whole thing - it probably came from jsfiddle, which usually does that. That's why I'm using jsbin now. I've inserted all of it manually into the ebay page you gave me and it works fine. If it happens to not work again, which I doubt it will, try using the web developer tools from your browser - see if the styles are applying, see if the html looks good. You can spot/fix all of your bugs with it.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/umisim/4/edit - your forgot to put the hash# behind your css id selectors.

Comment: oh yes :). please see http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=110954031764#ht_500wt_1156. can you see the way there is large gaps on hover compared to the original even though its the same code:  jsbin.com/obulog/1/edit? is there a reason for this?

Comment: sorry.. missed your last comment. taking a look

Comment: There's some whitespace in the html. Don't know how it got there. It's perhaps ebays html editor or whetever. Try switching the HTML with the one on this new jsbin http://jsbin.com/umisim/6/edit

Comment: you are the man :D. do you have an email address I can contact you with? very handy to have on board

Answer (score 1):

You're styling all unordered lists and list items. What!? You need to make your selectors very specific so you don't interfere with existing styles on the page.

You can wrap everything in a div and then use the [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) to select the ul and li.

Or, since you already have a ul#menu, use that in the CSS. `ul#menu { ... }` This will only style ul elements that have the "menu" ID. I'd still change the id from menu to something more specific in case the page has a ul with menu id, too.

Refrences: [Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

Comment: sorry im new to all this can you send a jsfiddle or update the existing

Comment: Replace all occurrences of `ul` in your CSS selectors with the more descriptive selector `ul#menu`

Comment: @user1667346 why did you replace `<ul>` with `<ul#menu>`? You need to replace instances of `ul` with `ul#menu` ***in your CSS only***. And remove the `<style>` tags from the CSS block in your JSFiddle.